# when i run my django project on terminal i get the AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'

Tags: python, django, rest, frameworks

When i run my Django app on terminal i get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7f51ce501aa0>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/macrewsupreet/heroku_wheredego1/wheredg-backend/macrewsupreet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/macrewsupreet/heroku_wheredego1/wheredg-backend/macrewsupreet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 116, in inner_run
        self.check(display_num_errors=True)
      File "/home/macrewsupreet/heroku_wheredego1/wheredg-backend/macrewsupreet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 426, in check
        include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
      File "/home/macrewsupreet/heroku_wheredego1/wheredg-backend/macrewsupreet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
        new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
      File "/home/macrewsupreet/heroku_wheredego1/wheredg-backend/macrewsupreet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
        return check_resolver(resolver)
      File "/home/macrewsupreet/heroku_wheredego1/wheredg-backend/macrewsupreet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 31, in check_resolver
        warnings.extend(check_pattern_startswith_slash(pattern))
      File "/home/macrewsupreet/heroku_wheredego1/wheredg-backend/macrewsupreet/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 67, in check_pattern_startswith_slash
        regex_pattern = pattern.regex.pattern
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'regex'
```

My main `urls.py` file

```
urlpatterns =[
        url(r'^api/account/', include("wheredego_service.accounts.account_urls")),
        url(r'^api/fileupload/', include("wheredego_service.file_manager.file_manager_urls")),
        url(r'^api/activity_category', include(
                               "wheredego_service.activity_category.activity_category_urls")),
        url(r'^api/destination', include("wheredego_service.destinations.destination_urls")),
        url(r'^api/trip', include("wheredego_service.trip.trip_urls")),
        url(r'^api/bucket', include("wheredego_service.bucket.bucket_urls")),
        url(r'^api/experience', include("wheredego_service.experience.experience_urls")),
        url(r'^api/region', include("wheredego_service.region.region_urls")),
        url(r'^api/friend', include("wheredego_service.friend.friend_urls")),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is My Trip app's views and i have followed the same pattern in all url files.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from wheredego_service.trip import trip_views
from wheredego_service.trip.itinerary import itinerary_views

urlpatterns =[
url(r'^/(?P<trip_id>[0-9,a-z,_]+)/itinerary', itinerary_views.ListItineraryTripView.as_view()), url(r'^/me', trip_views.ListMyTripsView.as_view()), ]
```

Please help how to resolve this error.

Comment: Please post the contents of your project's `urls.py` where the problem is coming from. You have an error in one of your URL definitions.

Comment: i have different apps in project and each app is having different url file . should i post all or main url file?

Comment: This is my main url file

Comment: The error is in one of the individual app's URL definitions... of which you have quite a lot!

Comment: i have posted my one of the apps urls could you please take a look

Answer (score 1):

In one of your `urls.py` files, you have a string in the list of URL patterns. This could be because you forgot to remove the prefix when you switched from `patterns(prefix, ...)` to a list of `url()`s.

You need to look through your urls.py and find something like:

```
urlpatterns =[
    '' # <- this is the problem, remove this string
    url(...)
    url(...)
]
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible for us to tell which `urls.py` the problem is in. You could try commenting out the `includes()` one by one. If the error stops, then you've found the one that's causing the problem.

In Django 1.10, the url checks have improved slightly, the `check_pattern_startswith_slash` won't fail any more, and you'll get a specific warning about the string instead.